# How to read to an existing Excel spreadsheet cell (or cells)

Tags: excel, vb.net, winforms

(If my question or description is too vague please correct me)

I want to read data from cells in an excel spreadsheet (Not everything, just a couple cells) from WinForms, use that data and display it as the Labels' text.
A good example of this would be, someone who has their product's inventory stored in a spreadsheet but just wants to know the number of x product that exists in his inventory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
xlApp = New Excel.Application
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add("Your file path here")
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1") ' Your sheet name is here
Label1.Text = xlWorkSheet.Range("B2").Value 'cell no from where you want to fetch data
```

Comment: You don't need to create a new instance of excel. You are already in excel. Also, if it is an existing workbook, you can just use: `Workbooks.Open` method

Comment: Thanks, I did try it out but I got the following error: `'Workbooks' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Application'`

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something or it has to do with the fact that I'm using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: My bad, I had to import `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. Thanks for all your help, you really helped me out. This might be a dumb question or better asked in a seperate post but is there a way to edit cells?

Comment: "xlWorkSheet.Range("B2").Value = Label1.Text"   in above code..